# ng-click first apply class, then execute function

Tags: angularjs, function, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-ng-click, delayed-execution

I have a shopping cart (a rootScope array) which gets turned into a list of items in it, including a button to delete that item from the cart array (the red X).

[I don't have enough reputation to add an image, so here's a link to what it looks like](http://gyazo.com/0fc2eb3e1e71d3c50bd70bb4362587ac)

What I want to have happen is when I click one of the red X buttons, the item first does an animation(some sort of fade out), and then the actual cart has the item spliced from it. Using ng-click I am able to either do one or the other, but not both. When both is applied the animation doesn't trigger because it doesn't have time to. Is there a way to wait for the animation to finish, then perform the function?

(the animation executed by applying a class to the div on ng-click, so possibly a watch for class change?)

Here's my code. The code won't work in the snippet but you can see my functions and html.

```js
$scope.removeFromCart = function(removedGame) {
        index = $rootScope.cartArray.indexOf(removedGame);
        $rootScope.cartArray.splice(index, 1);
    };


$(".disappear").hasClass('fadeOutRight')(function(){
   $scope.removeFromCart(cartArray[0]) ;
});
```

```css
.cartGameDiv {
    height: 140px;
    width: auto;
}
```

```html
<div ng-repeat = "newGame in cartArray" ng-class="disappear">
        <div>
            <div class="col-sm-11 col-lg-11 col-md-11 cartGameDiv">
                <div class="thumbnail">
                    <div class="pull-left">
                        <img style="height: 100px; width: 213px; padding: 5px; margin-top: 5px" src="{{newGame.thumbnail}}" alt="">
                        <div id="ratingDiv" style="margin-left: 8px; margin-right: 8px; margin-bottom: 5px;">
                            <div style="display: inline-block" ng-bind-html="getTrustedHtml(newGame)"></div>
                            <p class="pull-right" style="color: #d17581">{{newGame.numberReviews}} reviews</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="caption">
                        <h4 style="margin-top: 0" class="pull-right">{{newGame.price}}</h4>
                        <h4 style="margin-top: 0"><a class="categoryGameName" href="#details/{{myGamesList.indexOf(newGame)}}">{{newGame.name | removeSubName}}</a>
                        </h4>
                        <p>{{newGame.description.substring(0,290) + '...'}}</p>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-1 col-lg-1 col-md-1 cartGameDiv">
            <img style="margin-bottom: 10px; margin-top: 10px;" src="images/glyphIconCheckmark.png" alt=""/>
            <img ng-click="disappear='animated fadeOutRight'; removeFromCart(newGame)" style="margin-bottom: 10px" src="images/glyphIconRemoveGame.png" alt=""/>
            <img src="images/glyphIconLike.png" alt=""/>
        </div>
    </div>
```

If you have any idea how to delay the function call until after the animation I'd really appreciate it! Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is very simple to do using [ngAnimate](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngAnimate). Add the ngAnimate script to your page (you can get this from numerous CDNs), include ngAnimate as a dependency to your module and then just add some simple CSS.

```
.ng-leave{
    -webkit-animation: fadeOutRight 1s;
    -moz-animation: fadeOutRight 1s;
    -o-animation: fadeOutRight 1s;
    animation: fadeOutRight 1s;
}
```

In your example, you need not do any work applying the class yourself, ngAnimate will do it for you.

Here is a [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/N8NGesHliOVCLXALp7hG?p=preview) demonstrating how you would do it.

Comment: Hi sorry I'm so late, I had a busy weekend! I tried what you stated and for some reason whenever I include ngAnimate as a dependency it breaks my site (none of the ngRepeats load and some of the formatting doesn't load). From what you've stated, and especially from the Plunker example (thank you so much for that! it's extremely helpful), I assume that your answer is a correct fix. I just have to figure out this issue with ngAnimate. I'll update this post once I fix it! Cheers.

Comment: Wow i'm not sure why I never tried this before, but I used the exact sources that you used on your Plunker demo and it worked! Before I had tried downloading angular-animate from [link](angularJS.org), and I had tried their CDN, but it didn't. I'm not sure why, but your sources did work, so thanks again!